# Can't open any jetbrains products - no obvious errors

Tags: snap

I have phpstorm, datagrip, and pycharm installed on my machine. When I click on any of their icons in my favourites bar (which up until now worked) the  cursor goes into a loading state, then the name appears along my top bar, then nothing.

No error messages appear, I've tried restarting the machine, I've done a snap refresh, I've even tried uninstalling and reinstalling phpstorm.

I can see no java processes on my system monitor.

I can open phpstorm however by navigating to the bin folder:

```
~/PhpStorm-202.7660.42/bin$ ./phpstorm.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
```

After this warning it starts up, and I can see a java process in system monitor.

I am looking to have the icons in my favourites bar working again, as doing this every time I want to open my IDE is tedious (and I'm not even sure how to run datagrip using the terminal, that's really slowing me down this morning.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suggest you to use [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) ([download](https://data.services.jetbrains.com/products/download?platform=linux&code=TBA)) over snap, the issues here are that snap and GUI integration aren't great at all so icons can be broken at any time (and official realeases are 99% of the time more up to date that those on package manager)

Comment: Hi, this worked. Really surprised I hadn't come across that one, thanks so much for pointing me to it, I can finally get datagrip started :D

Comment: Thanks. You saved my life :))